# Invalid get index '1' (on base: 'Array') GODOT path finding

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to make a bird that follows a Position2D node attached to the character.(The Position2D node is in group called birdpos) When I run the game as soon as the bird is on screen (screendetector) it goes to the Position2D node. However once it reaches its destination it gives me the error "Invalid get index '1' (on base: 'Array')." (im also getting jittering when it reaches position) Im sure this is an easy fix, here is my code

```
extends KinematicBody2D
export(int) var SPEED: int = 100
var velocity: Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO

var path: Array = []
var levelNavigation: Navigation2D = null
var birdpos = null
onready var line2d = $Line2D #shows pathing
func _ready():
    var tree = get_tree()
    $flyingsprite1/AnimationPlayer.play("flying")
    if tree.has_group("LevelNavigation"):
        levelNavigation = tree.get_nodes_in_group("LevelNavigation")[0]



func move():
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)






func _on_screenchecker_area_entered(area):
    $Timer.start()
    print("ligma")
    yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
    var tree = get_tree()
    if tree.has_group("LevelNavigation"): #navigation node
        levelNavigation = tree.get_nodes_in_group("LevelNavigation")[0]
    if tree.has_group("birdpos"): #Position2D that is attached to player
        birdpos = tree.get_nodes_in_group("birdpos")[0]


func _on_screenchecker_area_exited(area):
    print("liga")
    $Timer.stop()
    var birdpos = null
    var levelNavigation: Navigation2D = null
    
    
func _on_Timer_timeout():
    line2d.global_position = Vector2.ZERO
    if birdpos and levelNavigation:
        generate_path()
        
        
func _physics_process(delta):
    if Global.player.facing_right == true:
        $flyingsprite1.scale.x = -1
    else:
        $flyingsprite1.scale.x = 1
    if birdpos and levelNavigation:
        navigate()
    move()
    
    

func generate_path():
    if levelNavigation != null and birdpos != null:
        path = levelNavigation.get_simple_path(global_position, birdpos.global_position, false)
        line2d.points = path

func navigate():
    if path.size() > 0:
        velocity = global_position.direction_to(path[1]) * SPEED
        if global_position == path[0]:
            path.pop_front()
```

edit: Updated Code

```
extends KinematicBody2D
export(int) var SPEED: int = 200
var velocity: Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO
var path: Array = []
var levelNavigation: Navigation2D = null
var birdpos = null
onready var line2d = $Line2D

func _ready():
    # speed is distance over time
    
    var tree = get_tree()
    $flyingsprite1/AnimationPlayer.play("flying")
    #if tree.has_group("Player"):
        #player = tree.get_nodes_in_group("Player")[0]












func _on_screenchecker_area_exited(area):
    $Timer.stop()
    var birdpos = null
    var levelNavigation: Navigation2D = null
    
    
func _on_Timer_timeout():
    line2d.global_position = Vector2.ZERO
    if birdpos and levelNavigation:
        generate_path()
        
func _physics_process(delta):
    if path.size() == 0:
        return
        var levelNavigation: Navigation2D = null
        var birdpos = null
        var next := global_position.move_toward(path[0], SPEED * delta)
    
        var displacement := next - global_position
        # And divide by it delta to get velocity:
        move_and_slide(displacement/delta)
    if Global.player.facing_right == true:
        $flyingsprite1.scale.x = -1
    else:
        $flyingsprite1.scale.x = 1
    if birdpos and levelNavigation:
        navigate()
    move()
func _input(event):
    if Input.is_key_pressed(KEY_Q):
        var tree = get_tree()
        
func _on_screenchecker_area_entered(area):
    $Timer.start()
    yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
    var tree = get_tree()
    if tree.has_group("LevelNavigation"):
        levelNavigation = tree.get_nodes_in_group("LevelNavigation")[0]
    if tree.has_group("birdpos"):
        birdpos = tree.get_nodes_in_group("birdpos")[0]
    

func generate_path():
    if levelNavigation != null and birdpos != null:
        if is_instance_valid(birdpos):
            path = levelNavigation.get_simple_path(global_position, birdpos.global_position, false)
            line2d.points = path
func navigate():
    if path.size() > 1:
        velocity = global_position.direction_to(path[1]) * SPEED
    if path.size() == 0:
        path.pop_front()
        

    

func move():
    if path.size() == 0:
        return
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The error

In this code:

```
    if path.size() > 0:
        velocity = global_position.direction_to(path[1]) * SPEED
        if global_position == path[0]:
            path.pop_front()
```

You check if the `path` has more than 0 points with `path.size() > 0`. That is, you are checking if the `path` has at least 1 point.

But to access `path[1]`, the path must have at least 2 points.

Thus, if the `path` has exactly 1 point, it will pass the check `path.size() > 0` and fail when reading `path[1]`.

I don't know when the path would have exactly one point. *It is not documented how this could happen, and it could be a problem with the navigation, it could even be a bug in Godot.* But, as far as I can tell it is happening for you.

Presumably you want to reach `path[0]` instead of `path[1]` since that is what you are checking against to remove points.

*If you do in fact want `path[1]`, then check if the path has at least 2 points with `path.size() > 1` (or `path.size() >= 2` if you prefer).*

---

### The jitter

*I'm assuming here that `path[0]` is the target.*

I believe it is three things:

- **You cannot trust vector equality**

  Vector equality boils down to equality of the components. Which is float equality. And thus Vector equality has all the problems of float equality.

  So, to compare to your current target use `is_equal_approx`. For example `global_position.is_equal_approx(path[0])`.
- **You don't want to move if you reached the target**

  This is easy enough: If there are no more points in `path`, don't move. That is, you can add this at the start of `move`:

  ```
  if path.size() == 0:
      return
  ```

  *If you will have the code in `_physics_process` instead of `move`, remember to check there.*
- **You don't want to overshoot**

  So, `move_and_slide` will move the object as much as it should given the time between physics frames (`delta`). But that might be more than necessary to reach the target. As consequence, it is very likely to overshoot the target. As a result, the next physics frame it will have to move in the opposite direction, and overshoot again, and so on… Jitter!

  I'll give you three solutions:

  1. Don't use `move_and_slide` (with the caveat that you would be forgoing physics collisions):

     ```
     # you can use move_toward
     global_position = global_position.move_toward(path[0], SPEED * delta)
     ```
  2. Let us keep `move_and_slide`, but compute the displacement we want.

     ```
     # you can use move_toward
     var next := global_position.move_toward(path[0], SPEED * delta)
     # Then compute the displacement
     var displacement := next - global_position
     # And divide by it delta to get velocity:
     move_and_slide(displacement/delta)
     ```
  3. Again, using `move_and_slide`, but this time we figure out the maximum speed to not overshoot:

     ```
     # speed is distance over time
     var max_speed := global_position.distance_to(path[0])/delta
     # And we clamp!
     move_and_slide(velocity.clamped(max_speed))
     ```

  *For the versions of the code that use `delta` you can either put the code in `_physics_process`, or pass `delta` to `move` as a parameter. Also don't forget the check for `path.size()` mentioned in the prior point.*

---

**Addendum** If you use `path[0]` as target, but it was equal to the current position, you would get about no velocity, and have to waste a physics frame. Consider this rewrite:

```
    if path.size() > 0 and global_position.is_equal_approx(path[0]):
        path.pop_front()

    if path.size() > 0:
        velocity = global_position.direction_to(path[0]) * SPEED
```

Comment: i was able to fix the error but the jittering still remains. i dont want to get rid of move and slide so i tried the second option. i put it under physics_process(delta). When i run the code i get the same error code "Invalid get index '0' (on base: 'Array')."    When i try the third option i get the error "Invalid type in function 'distance_to' in base 'Vector2'. Cannot convert argument 1 from String to Vector2" and i set the target to birdpos. When i set the target to the player (Global.player.global_position) the bird only moves when it is in contact with the position2D

Comment: @JacobWhisenand For the first one, the object got to the end of the path, now the path is empty. You don't want to move in that situation. Which is why I said to do this `if path.size() == 0: return`. The second one is my fault, I forgot to change `target` to `path[0]` when I posted the code here. It should be `distance_to(path[0])`. And that would also need the check. I'll fix that in the answer. Edit: answer updated.

Comment: i am still unable to get it to work. It is still jittery when it reaches the position2D (birdpos). I have updated the post with the new code

Comment: @JacobWhisenand `if path.size() == 0: path.pop_front()` Means that when the path is empty you remove from it. And the idea of `if path.size() == 0: return` is to short circuit. That is, if the path is empty, exit the function and do nothing else. But instead of doing `if path.size() > 0:` and having all your code inside, you can do `if path.size() == 0: return` and have your code outside (after) the if. I hope that makes sense. I don't know if you want to use `move_and_slide` in `move` or `_physics_process`. You have both, pick one. And you are still using `path[1]`, is `path[1]` correct?